# PHP/ASP Trouble understanding

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net

I am coming from a .Net background, and I'm trying to familiarize myself with PHP.
So far, it's been less then fun.

What I don't understand is the languages' obsession with multiple pages, tons of AJAX calls with JQuery.

But maybe I am doing something wrong?

I am trying to make a simple login page that might look like this in ASP

```
<body runat="server">
    <div id="form-container runat="server">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:Label ID="usernameLabel" runat="server"  Text="Username:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="username" Text="" runat="server" />

        <asp:Label ID="passwordLabel" runat="server"  Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="password" Text="" runat="server" />

    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then, on my backpage I could reference the ASP elements almost like accessing html from a css file by calling something like this...

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Text)){
//do something
}
else if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Text){
//do something 
}
else{
// attempt login
}
```

But in PHP the guides I see are telling me to create stand-alone php pages, and use Jquery to interact with that server-side code. So I have to construct enormous amounts of code just to get replicate a login like above.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this just the difference between php and asp? 
Or in other words, how could I embed my php functions onto my webpages, and interact with the php elements as I do with asp?

As always, thanks.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. jQuery and AJAX have nothing to do with PHP per se; you could just as easily have used them or not with ASP.NET.

Comment: @EdCottrell Well, the guides I am seeing ALL seem to use Jquery/Ajax in order to utilize PHP. How could I have not used JQuery/Ajax and produced a similar structure with PHP? Sorry if that was not indicative of my initial question.

Comment: Use an HTML form and submit to a PHP page. The named elements will be accessible via `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on the method used...or maybe i'm misreading this after relooking at it..

Comment: @Christopher I don't know what guides you're looking at, but again, jQuery and AJAX have nothing to do with PHP. jQuery is a JavaScript library. AJAX is a JavaScript technology for communicating client-to-server and back again without navigating to a new page. You can handle POST data in PHP just like in ASP.NET; you don't have to use jQuery. It sounds like you need to search for a basic form-processing tutorial in PHP; whatever you are looking at is not what I would call "basic."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you don't have the concept of the code-behind that you have in ASP.Net. PHP uses server tags on the HTML page itself. Also PHP does not have server controls like ASP.Net, just use the HTML controls.

Like in ASP.Net, you don't need Ajax or jQuery to implement the login page you're talking about. You did not put too much code, but here is a quick translation of your code to PHP:

```
<body>
    <div id="form-container>
    <form id="form1" action="">
        <span id="usernameLabel">Username:</span>
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <span id="passwordLabel">Password:</span>
        <input type="text" id="password" />
    </form>
    </div>
<?php
    if($_POST["username"]) != null && $_POST["username"]) != ""){
        //do something
    }
    else if($_POST["password"]) != null && $_POST["password"]) != ""){
        //do something 
    }
    else{
        // attempt login
    }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a good explanation, though you could simplify the `if(blah != null && blah != "")` conditions to `if(!empty(blah))`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was more or less looking for. This is way more helpful then the articled I was able to find on Google.

Comment: Actually, this still isn't really what I was looking for... seeing as in order to POST, you have to redirect by default. In order to POST without redirecting to a new page, you have to use AJAX. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806028/post-without-redirect-with-php       .... in ASP, this is not necessary. I do not have to redirect to get my C# function to do something.

Comment: Actually you're wrong. It is exactly the same in ASP.Net. You cannot POST without submitting the form (i.e. redirect). ASP.Net does that automatically for you. Check the HTML source of any ASP.Net page and you will see the JavaScript code that submits the page. In both PHP and ASP.Net you need to use Ajax if you don't want to reload the whole page. There is no difference because both are based on HTML which is the foundation. Microsoft just automated a lot of stuff so ASP.Net developers don't know what's going under the hood.

Comment: @RacilHilan Okay, I believe you. It is just that I would rather not bother to write tons of code to get a very, very small project to work. I am thinking I choose the wrong technology for my project.

Comment: Well, that's the idea behind ASP.Net and most of other development frameworks from Microsoft. They call it **Rapid Development** :-). You don't need to use Ajax. The code in my answer works exactly like ASP.Net. I left the form's `action` empty to mimic ASP.Net behaviour. In ASP.Net, the page submits to itself so the code-behind magic happens. It then automatically grabs the POST data, loops through them and maps them to the server controls, so you get the values like `username.Text`. In PHP, you will have to do that by yourself, so you get the POST, grab it directly like `$_POST["username"])`

Comment: @RacilHilan Then that makes sense to me. I guess starting with ASP and getting great results in a few days really soiled my attitude when trying to achieve the same in the same amount of time as PHP. Thank you for all your answers and insight, much appreciated. I will have to go out and grab some basic texts for PHP development and really start to understand all of this.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, ASP.Net really spoils developers and I've worked with many developers who don't understand the basic fundamentals of HTML because it is all hidden from them in ASP.Net. If you feel that you don't completely understand how the HTML forms work, how they submit the data in URL using GET, and how they submit the data using POST, and how Ajax is different and how it works, then I highly recommend you to spend a few hours studying all of those fundamentals before you start PHP, otherwise you will have a hard time figuring out how to do stuff in PHP.